# Hyperledger Composer v0.19 Error when starting the business network

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I follow the step in [download pre-requisite](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/installing-prereqs.html) and then [installing development environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools.html). Now I stuck at [developer tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) :step 4 number 2 start the business network. I stuck at this error few days :(

THIS IS MY ERROR:

```
composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

Starting business network tutorial-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:
userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Unable to initalize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [composerchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
Command failed

I follow the hyperledger tutorial:
installing prerequisite - installing development environment - developer tutorial

Comment: Hyperledger composer is end of life and as such all development has stopped and the community has moved on. You should use hyperledger fabric instead https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/getting_started.html
(Hyperledger composer was just a layer on top of hyperledger fabric and a lot of it's concepts were migrated to hyperledger fabric)

Comment: @david_k Alright, thank you for informing me. However, based on my research Hyperledger composer still can use right? If I'm wrong please correct me

Comment: I've no idea, it could very well suffer from what is called "bitrot" and stop working, but you may get it to work problem is if you face any problems it's very likely you won't get any response to questions as no one is using it anymore. I can tell you it uses a very old version of hyperledger fabric as well so unlikely you will get much help there either. Better to use hyperledger fabric 2.2 as you are more likely to find like minded users

Comment: Thank you again for answering my question. I have solved this problem:)